# Column not found with Translatable in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, translation

Hi want to use the Translatable Behaviour from the Doctrine Extensions ins Symfony2.

I use Doctrine and after some tries with my own classes I 100% copied the Article class from

http://gediminasm.org/article/translatable-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2

in my project and only adapted the namespace. But I get an Exception:

```
[2/2] DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.title AS title2, t0.content AS content3 FROM articles t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params {"1":1}:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.content' in 'field list'
```

The MySql Query that is sent is

```
    SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.title AS title2, t0.content AS content3 FROM articles t0 WHERE t0.id = 1
```

Why does Doctrine/Symfony tries to access articles instead of ext_translations. If I use a TranslationEntity, everything works fine, so I am sure, that the translatable is activated in my config. But here is my config to make everything clear

config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types:

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    gedmo_translatable:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoTranslatable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                        is_bundle: false
                    gedmo_translator:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoTranslator # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                        is_bundle: false
                    gedmo_loggable:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoLoggable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                        is_bundle: false
                    gedmo_tree:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoTree # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                        is_bundle: false

stof_doctrine_extensions:
        default_locale: en_us
        translation_fallback: true
        orm:
            default:
              timestampable: true
              translatable: true
              sluggable: true
```

Does anyone has an idea why this is not working? Thanks a lot for your help